# Authorization Header not being sent to Maven Repository

Tags: java, maven

I am currently building my own Maven Repository. I am trying to add support for private repositories. However, I configured my repo here

pom.xml

```xml
        <repository>
            <id>kingtux-dev</id>
            <name>My Developer Repo</name>
            <url>http://127.0.0.1:6742/storages/public/maven</url>
        </repository>
```

settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
     <servers>
      <server>
         <id>kingtux-dev</id>
         <username>user</username>
         <password>password</password>
      </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```

My software does not detect any sort of Authorization header though.

The only headers it finds is

```
cache-control: no-cache
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
cache-store: no-store
user-agent: Apache-Maven/3.6.3 (Java 11.0.11; Linux 5.11.0-7633-generic)
host: 127.0.0.1:6742
connection: Keep-Alive
pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: Doing that out of curiosity? Apart from that If I correctly remember the repository will tell Maven (wagon) that an authorization is needed and after that the authorization is sendet..I would suggest to use a working repo manager and check via a http proxy and see what's happening.. or take a look into existing code https://github.com/dzikoysk/reposilite

Comment: I am currently digging through Reposlite.

Comment: If you don't return any auth error, there is no point to send auth headers. What's your server's code? Do you have any or using Reposlite and only that? maybe this is just free-for-all config?

Comment: I solved my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69128640/12587452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was as kmarbaise suggested.

Return a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate on a failure to authenticate and Maven will return will the authorization header.